# XUL: how to persist a value of a textbox?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox extension that contains a textbox:

```
<textbox id="exclude-text" flex="1" rows="10" multiline="true" style="min-width: 25em;" wrap="off" value="0" persist="value"/>
```

A user enters some text in the text box. I need this text to persist across sessions.
I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Persistent_Data) info on the "persist attribute", but in my case it does not work.
Is there any way to make it work or any simple workaround?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `persist` attribute can only store attributes - yet the `value` attribute of a text field doesn't change when text is being entered, only the `value` property. As far as I know, the only work-around is keeping the `value` attribute in sync with the `value` property manually, something like this:

```
<textbox id="exclude-text" value="0" persist="value"
oninput="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);document.persist(this, 'value')"/>
```

Calling `document.persist()` is necessary unfortunately, changing attributes manually normally doesn't trigger persistance.

For reference: this is [bug 111486](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111486), a XUL limitation first noted in 2001.

Comment: Hi, Wladimir! Wow, it works! Thank you for such a complete answer. I already abandoned my hopes with the "persist" attribute and coded using the Preferences System, but your solution is much more elegant. A nice and simpler alternative to preferences, especially when you do not really need them.